# Changing the data type of a JSON field

Tags: java, android, json, hex

Im new to Json and have a question about sending hex data across from client to the server. At the moment I have my class bean set up like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "SIG")
public class Sig {
    /** The id of the transaction */
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private Long id;
    /** The data associated with the signature */
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY, columnDefinition = "BLOB")
    private byte[] data;

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(final byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

The problem im having is that when it sends across via JSON to the server I want the 'data' field to be represented as Hexadecimal. Are there any limitations to just changing the 'getData()' method to the following?:

```
public String getData() {
    //Code which converts data to hex
    data = data.toHex();
    return data;
}
```

Is changing this get method to a String going to mess JSON up? Or is there a better way of converting this to Hex?

Answer (score 0):

The json is a string you can send Hex, Base64, or anything; any type will be convert in String

Comment: So is it fine to keep the field as a byte array but just change the get method to return a String?

Comment: i think that the best way is change the type when you gonna send the json